# How do I get letters in the inputs and change writing in the div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried code snippet below entering i in the first and x in the second input but `Change this writing` didn't change into `Change thxs wrxtxng`

Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
var d = document.getElementById("d").innerHTML
var Btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var inp1 = document.getElementById("i1").value;
var inp2 = document.getElementById("i2").value;
Btn.addEventListener("click",change);
function change() {
    var yeni = d.replaceAll(inp1,inp2);
    document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = yeni;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="d">Change this writing</div><br>
<input id="i1" type="text">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input id="i2" type="text"><br><br>
<button id="btn" class="btn btn-danger">Change</button>
```

Comment: You are reading the values of the user's input before they have input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place `console.log(inp1, inp2);` inside the `change` function, you'll see that there don't hold the expected value.

You're defining them **before** the user has any time to insert the value.

Easiest fix would be to call `getElementById` inside the function when the button is pressed:

```js
var Btn = document.getElementById("btn");
Btn.addEventListener("click",change);

function change() {
    var inp1 = document.getElementById("i1").value;
    var inp2 = document.getElementById("i2").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("d");
   
    var yeni = d.innerHTML.replaceAll(inp1, inp2);
    d.innerHTML = yeni;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="d">Change this writing</div><br>
<input id="i1" type="text" >&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input id="i2" type="text"><br><br>
<button id="btn" class="btn btn-danger">Change</button>
```

Comment: And you could skip the overhead of adding an event listener to the button if you define the button like: <button id="btn" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="change()">Change</button>